# Exclude custom field in django admin form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using `django` form to add custom field in my form, but I want to exclude this custom field in some condition(when user_id is set on url query param), how can I handle it?

Something interesting happens in my try and error, I put my custom field name in `Mata.exclude` of my form, but this custom field still generates in my form !!!!

Here is my code:

```
class PushTokenForm(forms.ModelForm):

    push_scenario = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=_('Push Scenario'),
        choices=get_scenarios(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PushToken
        exclude = ['failed', 'push_scenario']
```

> UPDATE

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    self.exclude = []
    user_id = request.GET['user_id'] if 'user_id' in request.GET else None
    if user_id:
        self.exclude.append('push_scenario')
    form = super(PushTokenAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    return form
```

Comment: can you show us the code/view where you get/handle user_id together with the form?

Comment: @BogdanGoie user_id is a part of URL, i can't get it in `ModelForm` module, I should handle it in `ModelAdmin`

Comment: Could you show us your `ModelAdmin`? Where do you use that form? In the changeform view?

Comment: @AlexMorozov question updated